# AngularJS passing data to $http.get with parameters

Tags: angularjs, http

i want to get data from the server while passing the parameters with my URL

the URL is 'http://localhost:30005/myapp/minMaxProduct/12'

And the data i want to pass is 12 with the get request.

my angularjs code is

```
getProductFromMinJWS: function(event) {
      var config = {
        params: {
            maxMinVal: event
            }
          }
        return $http.get('http://localhost:30005/myapp/minMaxProduct/',config);
    },
```

the event is getting the value 12.but i get 404.can some one tell me the correct way to get data while passing parameters

Thanks

Comment: which version of angular are you using?

Comment: @Tony Samperi  AngularJS v1.5.8

Comment: this worked out ....return $http.get("http://localhost:30005/myapp/minMaxProduct/"+event);

Answer (score 0):

I would do this:

```
getProductFromMinJWS: function(event) {
    var ajaxConfig = {
      url: "http://localhost:30005/myapp/minMaxProduct/" + event,
      method: "GET"
    }
    return $http(config);
}
```

This is the corret way.

Comment: still getting 404

Comment: The answer is written badly. You want to add the params to the URL, but not by using query string. You should specify that!

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented like this

```
getProductFromMinJWS: function(url,data) {
    var obj = {
        url: url,
        async: true,
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    };
    if (typeof data != 'undefined' || data != null) {
        obj.params = data;
    }
    return $http(obj);
}
```